# macOS Mojave cmd+tab exposé doesn't change to active window

Tags: macos, mission-control

I've grown quite fond of the Mission Control way of thinking, but one thing annoys me.

When I use Cmd+tab to switch between applications
[image: Cmd-tab]

And then click down-arrow to see open instances of the app
[image: Exposé]

Now when I use left and right arrow, a blue border surrounds each instance of the apps. Now when I click on an instance that's on the desktop that I'm currently on, that instance is shown. But if I choose an instance that's on another desktop, the application is "focused", as is the application name appears to the top left, but the instance is not focused.

I expect the focused desktop to change to wherever the instance that I focused is located.

I have quite a thick set of macOS defaults that I'm using, so I guess that there could be some setting there that messes up things.

In case you want to see my defaults, I have them public [here](https://github.com/modestotech/dotfiles/blob/master/macos/setupMacOsDefaults.sh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing `defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-auto-swoosh -boolean NO`. This setting caused each desktop to be handled as one space for mission control, which wasn't my intention.